# Force String.Format "{0:P4}" to show + sign

Tags: devexpress

I have a decimal column in my Database where values are stored as 12.35
We show it as 12.35%
The client wants to show +12.35% if the value is positive(just for this one field).  How I do get it to show the +sign. 
We format the textedit as P4 in the getter String.Format("{0:P4}", value);

This is what I've tried:
I was able to do this by using Fomrat event handler. I am looking for a cleaner way instead of the below code.

```
    private void txtMargin_FormatEditValue(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ConvertEditValueEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            if (e.Value.ToString().IndexOfAny(new char[] { '-', '+' }) < 0)
            {
                string val = e.Value.ToString();
                val = val.Replace("%", "");
                e.Value = string.Format("+{0}", (Convert.ToDouble(val) / 100).ToString("P4"));
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                string val = e.Value.ToString();
                val = val.Replace("%", "");
                e.Value = (Convert.ToDouble(val) / 100).ToString("P4");
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void txtMargin_ParseEditValue(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ConvertEditValueEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            if (e.Value.ToString().IndexOf('%') < 0)
            {
                e.Value = (Convert.ToDouble(e.Value.ToString()) / 100).ToString("P4");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form load past this code :

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "+#0.0000% ;-#0.0000%";
        textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Numeric;
        textEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = false;

        textEdit1.Properties.EditFormat.FormatString = "+#0.0000% ;-#0.0000%";;
    }

And in you TextBox Handel the event "`CustomDisplayText`" as :

     private void textEdit1_CustomDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.CustomDisplayTextEventArgs e)
            {
             if (e.Value != null && !e.Value.Equals (""))
            e.DisplayText = (Convert.ToDouble(e.Value.ToString()) / 100).ToString("+#0.0000 % ;-#0.0000 %");

             }
```